# Why should my method be static?

Tags: java, methods, static, program-entry-point

Hi I have this piece of code and i am really confused to why i have to make the lel method static.The error is this "non static method cant be referred from static content". Usually when I create methods either to construct new objects or to manipulate objects in the main method I do not get this error message.Plus, i never declared e to be static!!. can someone please explain to me why this occurring?? Thank you :)

```
class x {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        int e= 2232;

        e= lel(e);

    }

    int lel(int k){
        return k+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two methods. When you read _non static method_, which method does that refer to?

Comment: When you read _cant be referenced from static context_, which context do you think that is (given that you have two methods and only one of them is `static`)?

Comment: Long story short static methods belong to class and not the object. Now take a look at your code. You are calling the non-static method lel without an object.

Comment: Change your code to `e = new x().lel(e);` -- you've created an _instance_ of `x` through which you can access `lel`, without requiring to change the method to `static`.

Comment: Quick question: what do you think `static` means?

Comment: There is nothing in the error message that tells you the method should be static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions you could implement. The first option is to make your `int lel(int k)` a static method which would look like `static int lel(int k)`

Your other option is to declare a new object of your class x and use that for your lel method within main as MickMnemonic suggested in the comments. That code would look like:

> e = new x().lel(e);

I believe the simplest thing would be to make the lel method static but it is up to you.

A deeper explanation of static methods can be found [here.](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-static-method-program)

Comment: 'Any code referenced within the main method must also be static' is simply untrue. Otherwise there could never be any non-static methods. Your own suggestion proves the point.

Comment: I was not thinking right when I wrote that, thank you for pointing it out, I removed it from my answer.